# XSLT : pipeDocument

Tags: xml, apache, xslt, xalan

**Setup :** Apache Xalan 2.7.1

**Input :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

**main.xslt:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xpi="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/PipeDocument">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>


  <xsl:template match="/">  
        <xpi:pipeDocument source="." >
               <stylesheet href="second.xslt"/>
        </xpi:pipeDocument>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**second.xslt :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">    
        <xsl:value-of select="note/to" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xpi:pipeDocument xmlns:xpi="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/PipeDocument" source=".">
<stylesheet href="second.xslt"/>
</xpi:pipeDocument>
```

**Desired Output :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
Tove
```

> **Question :**
>
> Comming from here: https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/apidocs/org/apache/xalan/lib/PipeDocument.html
>
> I really scratch my head about this one. How to properly use `source` and `target`??
>
> I wish to have currently input xml as `source` and `output` just as it was, standard `output.xml`.
>
> **Note: Only xslt 1.0 solutions are appreciated**

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#extension, if you want to tell the processor that that element is an extension element that serves as an instruction then you need to start by declaring `<xsl:stylesheet extension-element-prefixes="xpi" ...>`.

Comment: And `<xpi:pipeDocument source="." >` should be `<xpi:pipeDocument source="{.}" >`, no?

Comment: I dont mind `prefixes` the actuall value of the output is the problem. `second.xslt` is not being called for the piped transformation.

Comment: Well to tell the processor that you want `xpi:pipeDocument` to be treated as an instruction and not as a result element you have to declare `<xsl:stylesheet extension-element-prefixes="xpi" ...>`. I don't understand why, instead of doing that, you tell us you "dont mind prefixes", unless you confuse `exclude-result-prefixes` with `extension-element-prefixes`. But they are quite different attributes.

Comment: alright, that was a bit of misunderstanding. You are 100% correct about `extension-element-prefixes`. I'll update the q, after some testing

Comment: @MartinHonnen Please provide answer to this question with working example, `extension-element-prefixes` works like charm

Comment: If you got it working then consider to write an answer yourself, I don't have enough interest in Xalan specific stuff to try to write an answer with a fully tested example.

Comment: Sure I just wanted to grant you points for your help. Anyway Thank You for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Consider following template as a answer**

> Note that you need to have proper folder structure in order for this transformation to work. (second.xslt, thrid.xslt, output, input xmls)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xpi="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/PipeDocument"
    extension-element-prefixes="xpi">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />


  <xsl:template match="/">      
        <xpi:pipeDocument source="'source_file'" target="output_file">
               <stylesheet href="second.xslt"/>
               <stylesheet href="third.xslt"/>
        </xpi:pipeDocument>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```